# Why laravel search query does not working?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `users` table that has department and role. This is many to many relations. So following are the tables,

- users
- departments
- roles
- users_departments
- users_roles

With the following models,

1. User
2. Role
3. Department

In the User model I have the following

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function scopeSearch($query, $searchValues)
    {
        return $query->where('first_name','like', '%'.$searchValues.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name','like', '%'.$searchValues.'%')
        ->orWhere('email','like', '%'.$searchValues.'%');
    }
    
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'users_departments', 'user_id', 'department_id');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

I have a raw query that works for me, you can see it below

```
SELECT users.id as id, users.first_name as first_name, users.last_name as last_name, users.email as email, roles.title as `role`, departments.title as department 
FROM users INNER JOIN users_departments ON users_departments.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN departments ON departments.id = users_departments.department_id 
INNER JOIN users_roles ON users_roles.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users_roles.role_id 
WHERE `departments`.`title` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR `roles`.`title` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR `first_name` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR `last_name` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR `email` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY " . $orderColumnName. " " . $order
```

**What I tried?**

I am trying the following query which returns nothing,

```
$query = User::with([
    'roles' => function($query) use($searchValues) {
        return $query->where('title', 'LIKE','%'.$searchValues.'%');
    }, 
    'departments' => function($query) use($searchValues) {
        return $query->where('title', 'LIKE','%'.$searchValues.'%');

    }
])
->search($searchValues)
->orderBy($orderColumnName,$order)
->limit($request->length)
->get();
```

can someone kindly guide me on what is the issue so that I can fix it? I appreciate it if someone helps me to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: What is `search` method in your query? Is it a scope?

Comment: @MichalOravec yes true, I have mentioned in the question. You can see in the User model

Comment: When working with complex queries, I get the query right first as you've done and then dump the sql that's produced so you can compare it. Then just keep refining till you get them the same.

Comment: Just to add to that, I think you'll find that the ->with() will not be producing the result you want. You want an inner join so I'd be trying a ->join().

Answer (score 1):

Always be careful with `orWhere`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

> You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

But in your case it's a desired behavior.

You are missing filtering on your relationships, you can do that with `orWhereHas`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => $closure = function ($query) use ($searchValues) {
            return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$searchValues}");
        }, 'departments' => $closure
    ])->orWhereHas('roles', $closure)
    ->orWhereHas('departments', $closure)
    ->search($searchValues)
    ->orderBy($orderColumnName, $order)
    ->limit($request->length)
    ->get();
```

I saved closure to the variable because it's repeated in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it. Unfortunately it does not working

Comment: "It does not working" is not very helpful.